# Efficient way to compare more 50 strings

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I have method which takes two parameters one as `string` and other as `int`.

The  string has to compare with more than **50 string** and Once  the match is found int value need to be mapped with hard coded string as Example below

EX:

```
  string Compare_Method(std::string str, int val) {

     if(str == "FIRST")
{
  std::array<std::string, 3> real_value = {"Hello1","hai1","bye1"}
  return real_value[val];
}

     else if(str == "SECOND")
{
  std::array<std::string, 4> real_value = {"Hello2","hai2","bye2"}
  return real_value[val];
}

     else if(str == "THIRD")
{
  std::array<std::string, 5> real_value = {"Hello3","hai3","bye3"}
  return real_value[val];
}

//----- 50+ else if

}
```

My approach is as above. What will be the efficient way

**1.To compare more than 50 string.**

**2. create std::array for each if case**

**EDITED : std::array size is not fixed it can be 3,4,5 as edited above.**

Comment: Store your strings and string arrays in an `unordered_map`. This will be much more efficient. You can also form a composite key made of the string and the value and use that key to index the map.

Comment: Are the strings showed in the snippet just an example or the actual expected values?

Comment: @rim in all your `else if`'s you also make the array of `real_value` bigger but you don't add more strings to the array. Just in case you weren't aware of it :)

Comment: Just an idea: Maybe it is possible to think of an approach using [SMID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD). Not sure how this would actually look like with C++ though and for string operations it might also look quite ugly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would be my way of doing that. The data structure is created only once and the access times should be fast enough

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <unordered_map>

std::string Compare_Method(const std::string& str, int val)
{
    //                                  or std::vector<std::string>
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::array<std::string, 3>> map
    {
        {  "FIRST", { "Hello1", "hail1", "bye1" }},
        { "SECOND", { "Hello2", "hail2", "bye2" }},
        {  "THIRD", { "Hello3", "hail3", "bye3" }},
        // 50+ more
    };

    // maybe check if str is present in the map

    return map[str][val];
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << Compare_Method("SECOND", 1) << std::endl;
}
```

If `std::unordered_map` isn't (fast) enough for you, you can come up with some sort of static optimal hash structure, since keys are known at compile time.

Comment: you can also make a custom hashing function for std::unordered_map to make it faster, since the keys are known

Comment: Using the at() or operator [] on unordered_map is risky game as if passed first parameter to the function is not present in unordered_map then you have to face the out_of_bound exception.
Better use the find().

Comment: @Romen I took these into account. Just note the comments in my code.

Comment: @Mannoj Yeah, that's why the comment `maybe check if str is present in the map` is there. If the OP will make sure not to call `Compare_Method` with invalid argument, `find` is not necessary.

Comment: My personal preference would be to use `find` anyway, to avoid having the code used by `operator[]` to insert the key and a default value when calling `map[str]` and possible performance hit creating a default value to insert should `str` not be found.

Comment: @Zereges, our program should have the capability to hande it. The answer is a bit specific with limitations.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm OP can decide what to do on their own. I don't (at least I didn't at all) see what is their plan to do with this. That's why the comments are their for OP to decide whether they want to apply them or not.

Comment: @Zereges how about boundary check when std::vector<std::string> is used instead. if i access map[str][1000] ?

Comment: @rim If you want boundary checks, use `map.at(str).at(val)`, which will throw an exception if the value is not found.

Answer (score 2):

If those 50 strings are something you will be widely using throughout your program, `string` comparisons will take a toll on performance. I'd suggest you to adapt them to an `enum`.

```
enum Strings
{
    FIRST,
    SECOND,
    THIRD,
    …
    …
}
```

You'll obviously need a method to convert `string` to `int` whenever you get one from the source (user input, file read, etc.). This should be as infrequent as possible since your system now works on enum values (which can be used as indices on STL containers as we see in the next step)

```
int GetEnumIndex(const std::string& str)
{
    // here you can map all variants of the same string to the same number
    if ("FIRST" == str || "first" == str) return 1;
    …
}
```

Then, the comparison method can be based on the `enum` instead of the `string`:

```
std::string Compare_Method(const int& strIndex, int val)
{
    static std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> stringArray
    {
        { "Hello1", "hail1", "bye1" },
        { "Hello2", "hail2", "bye2", "aloha2" },
        { "Hello3", "hail3", "bye3", "aloha3", "tata3" },
        …
    };
    return stringArray[strIndex][val];
}
```

Comment: *You'll obviously need a method to convert `string` to `int`*, so your `GetEnumIndex` will perform a lots of comparsions as well.

Comment: You siad "string comparisons will take a toll on performance" but still GetEnumIndex do the string comparing ?

Answer (score 2):

With information provided by you, I tried various variations to find out best way to achieve objective. I am listing best one here. You can see other methods [here](https://github.com/manthanrtilva/stackoverflow/blob/master/59177728/Main.cpp).

You can compile it and run `run.sh` to compare performance of all cases.

```
std::string Method6(const std::string &str, int val) {
  static std::array<std::string, 5> NUMBERS{"FIRST", "SECOND", "THIRD",
                                            "FOURTH", "FIFTH"};
  static std::array<std::vector<std::string>, 5> VALUES{
      std::vector<std::string>{"FIRST", "hai1", "bye1"},
      std::vector<std::string>{"Hello1", "SECOND", "bye1"},
      std::vector<std::string>{"Hello1", "hai1", "THIRD"},
      std::vector<std::string>{"FOURTH", "hai1", "bye1"},
      std::vector<std::string>{"Hello1", "FIFTH", "bye1"}};
  for (int i = 0; i < NUMBERS.size(); ++i) {
    if (NUMBERS[i] == str) {
      return VALUES[i][val];
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

For simplicity I have been using `NUMBERS` with length of 5 but you can use what ever length you want to.

`VALUES` is `std::array` of `std::vector` so you can add any number if element to `std::vector`.

> output from github code.
>
> ```
> Method1   880
> Method2   851
> Method3   7292
> Method4   989
> Method5   598
> Method6   440
> ```

You output may be different based on you system and system load at the time of execution.

Comment: link is invalid

Comment: @rim check now.

Comment: accepting this since i found more info and best approach

Comment: None of your other methods used [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) which can be measurably faster than `std::map` for lookups. I would test that variant of the map structure and include it for completeness of the answer. (It might even be *faster* than the method you chose for the answer?)

Comment: Your testing methodology seems biased as well, `Method6` only has to perform up to 5 string comparisons since you chose such a small size for `NUMBERS`. The original question stated that `NUMBERS` would actually be *at least* 50 elements long, which would cause the more efficient lookup structures like `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` to demonstrate their performance better. I made my own tests and found `std::unordered_map` to be 10 - 10000 times faster than linearly searching a `std::array` (depending on how far down the key was in the array, also on MSVC instead of GCC).

Comment: With a little effort would could sort `NUMBERS` (and similarly `VALUES`) then do a binary search instead of a linear one.

Comment: @Romen Can you please show the result of your test.

Comment: [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/romenhurst/a643d9fc537f4ee8e46ed3b9913f0349) of my test. I left out the inner array lookup because that operation would contribute the same complexity to both algorithms being tested. This test generates 1000 unique keys and shows that maps are **much** faster than linear array searches when n >> 5. I realize that *my* testing methodology may have problems too, but I'm not sure they would contribute a significant error to the ~100:1 difference we see in the tests. Zereges' answer deserves the bounty because it is much more optimal than this algo.

Comment: @rim, forgot to tag you. See comment above.